# My enemy fall from floor when I play button in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My enemy fallen from floor and continuously fallen when I play button in Unity where as my Transform

Position x 0.03 y -0.459 z -0.1

Use Gravity is marked

I also have applied rigid body on cube inside my enemy.

Comment: This is really unclear, and will need more information (edited into the question itself) to stop it from being put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to answer without code. 
Check your floor, there should be a Box collider or mesh collider attached to floor gameobject in order to stop your player from free fall.